# The following simple Javascript code isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple javascript code which is not working. It is very simple but I couldn't find any error. Share if you see an error.

```
<div>
<p onclick="close()" id="adve">SOme thing</p>
</div>
<script>
function close() {
document.getElementById("adve").style.left = "100px";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Without positioning that `left` property won't do anything

Comment: always activate the console in your browser when testing javascript.

Comment: @low_rents isn't still working. Dave Gomez that is true but I'm checking chrome elements and script isn't setting the value.

Comment: You should choose a different name for your function close is a function of the window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the function name close  which is the in built function in js([Close](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp)). You may change the function name like this.

```
<div>
<p onclick="close1();" id="adve">SOme thing</p>
</div>
<script>
function close1() {
    document.getElementById("adve").style.left = "100px";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use close() as a function. although you can use Close()

```js
function close() {
  document.getElementById("adve").style.color = "yellow";
}
function Close(){
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<p id="adve" onclick="close()">SOme thing</p>
<p id="demo" onclick="Close()">Click me to change my text color.</p>
```